# Editing output file structure with i18next-scanner

Tags: configuration, format, output, translation, i18next

I'm using i18next-scanner to generate translation files, and here's my configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
  input: [
    'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
    // Use ! to filter out files or directories
    '!src/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}'
  ],
  output: './src',
  options: {
    debug: true,
    func: {
      list: ['t'],
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    trans: false,
    lngs: ['en', 'vi'],
    defaultLng: 'en',
    defaultNs: 'common',
    defaultValue: function (lng, ns, key) {
      return key;
    },
    removeUnusedKeys: false,
    resource: {
      loadPath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      savePath: 'locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
      jsonIndent: 2,
      lineEnding: '\n'
    },
    nsSeparator: false, // namespace separator
    keySeparator: false, // key separator
    interpolation: {
      prefix: '{{',
      suffix: '}}'
    }
  }
};
```

However, it only creates files in the following format:

```
{
  "title": "title",
  "content": "content"
}
```

I want it to generate this format for all files:

```
{
  "Index": {
    "title": "title",
    "content": "content"
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?